# Add offline mode to a Flutter Web App - Service Workers/Pwas

Tags: google-chrome, web, flutter, dart, service-worker

I need to transform a Flutter app into a PWA and I'm trying to understand if this is possible without rewriting the code in AngularDart.

I did some research and I found out that first I need my Flutter App to become a Flutter Web App but nothing more.

There is also a StackOverflow question that speaks about this but answers are not complete

How to transform Flutter web app into a PWA?

I found some PWA examples with AngularDart, JS, etc... but nothing about a Flutter PWA.

*On the Flutter for Web homepage they mention PWAs but I didn't understand if it is already a feature or not.

Answer (score 1):

Something to start you off.

> Can we use Flutter for PWA (Progressive Web App) ?

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14868

> Google I/O 2019 announced https://flutter.dev/web

Flutter on Web is still in preview, but here's a *get started* page:

- https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web

Answer (score 1):

since early 2020, Flutter Web support service worker.

here's the feature on GitHub for your reference.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/48344